# Trying to add a search feature based on a tab delimited file

Tags: c#, parsing, search

Every Monday I receive an exported address book... My boss wants a program to access this information.  Yes there are many ways that make sense (like importing it into Outlook) but we are going the route of a stand alone app.  I have no control over the incoming file (information or format)  it currently arrives as a "tab" delimited file.  My code does exactly what it is currently designed to do.  However, I would like to add a search feature and I don't know if I can do it in the form I have it now, or if I need to change the way I am importing the information.

Tab file comes in ( Name (Fisrt_Last), Department, Title, Email, OfficePH, MobilePH).

I am parsing the file, and creating an Array list.  I want to be able to search by last name.  IS this possible? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //for (int i = 0; i < Program.contacts.Length; i++)
    //{
    //    listView1.Items.Add(Program.contacts.ElementAt(i).ToString());
    //}

    string name, department, title, emailAddress, officePhone, mobilePhone;
    ArrayList contacts = new ArrayList();

    using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
    {
        parser.SetDataSource("S:/DEPARTMENTS/INFO_TECH/PERM/short_cuts/Addressbook.txt");
        parser.ColumnDelimiter = '\t';
        parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
        parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 0;
        parser.MaxRows = 15000;
        parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

        while (parser.Read())
        {
            name = parser["Name"];
            department = parser["Department"];
            title = parser["Title"];
            emailAddress = parser["EmailAddress"];
            officePhone = parser["OfficePhone"];
            mobilePhone = parser["MobilePhone"];

            contacts.Add(new contact(name, department, title, emailAddress, officePhone, mobilePhone));
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = contacts;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "CName";
    }
}

private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string n = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).CName;
    string d = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).CDept;
    string t = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).CTitle;
    string em = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).CEmail;
    string o = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).COPhone;
    string m = ((contact)listBox1.SelectedItem).CMPhone;

    textBox1.Text = n;
    textBox2.Text = d;
    textBox3.Text = t;
    textBox4.Text = em;
    textBox5.Text = o;
    textBox6.Text = m;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to have an `ArrayList`? Can't you use a `List<Contacts>`?

Comment: Just change your `ArrayList` to `List<contact>` and use linq `var searchResult = contacts.Where(x=>x.lastName="search string").ToList();`

Comment: @Sach I am fresh out of school, no developer above me (sink or swim) Can you point me towards a good List<> resource?

Comment: Just use the generic list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and then - use LINQ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

Comment: so now I feel like an idiot.  I know what List(s) are, was just having a major brain malfunction.  However, I am not familiar with LINQ.  Thanks for the input.  I think I almost have my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would create a `Contact` class. This is a simplified version of yours with only Name and Department.

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

I would then separate the reading part and put it in a method. Instead of an `ArrayList`, simply use a `System.Collections.List`, as follows:

```
public static void ReadContacts(out List<Contact> contacts)
{
    contacts = new List<Contact>();
    using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
    {
        parser.SetDataSource("S:/DEPARTMENTS/INFO_TECH/PERM/short_cuts/Addressbook.txt");
        parser.ColumnDelimiter = '\t';
        parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
        parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 0;
        parser.MaxRows = 15000;
        parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

        while (parser.Read())
        {
            contacts.Add(new Contact() { Name = parser["Name"], Department = parser["Department"] });
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to search the generated list, using `LINQ`, I would do the following. This is assuming an example of a first names looks like `Jane_Doe` (which is what I understood from your example).

```
List<Contact> contacts = null;
ReadContacts(out contacts);

listBox1.DataSource = contacts;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "CName";

string searchName = "Doe";
var result = contacts.Where(x => x.Name.Split('_')[1] == searchName);
```

Comment: I already have the contacts class.  Thanks for the visual.  I think I go it.  I'll be back after I give this a shot.

Comment: You're welcome. And depending on what actually your `Name` looks like, you might have to change your `Where()` search pattern.

Comment: I would not rely on splitting the name string and accessing name by index, because that is vulnerable to bad input. Consider simply using `string.Contains` instead

Comment: @ironstone13 good suggestion. Let me update the answer.

Comment: On second thoughts though, the OP wants to search by `Last Name`, and if the `First Name` contains the search string but the `Last Name` doesn't, `Contains()` would fail.

Comment: Actually did go with the .contains option.  That way, if for some reason they want to, they can search by First Name.  Also added a search by Department.  Now... how to make it time out... Everyday is a learning experience.  You guys are awesome.